# Dojo Filtering Select using REST viewItemFileService data store

Tags: xpages-extlib, xpages-ssjs

By following exactly this example http://www.ibmpressbooks.com/articles/article.asp?p=1924777&seqNum=6 but no luck.  I am trying to do the same thing but only have one column "Activity" in a view "Activity" that has thousands of activities.  I do not want to list all of them in SelectItems because of bad performance by speed although it is working (REST is NOT used in this approach).  I want to use REST because it is not loaded all activities and take advantage of type ahead functionality.  I tested on RESTClient and fond that my service is working.  The xpages is shown on a new open window after clicking a hostspot link.  Not sure what I am missing.  Please help.

My code as below.

```
<xe:restService id="restActivity" jsId="activityStore" pathInfo="viewActivity">
    <xe:this.service>
     <xe:viewItemFileService viewName="lkpActivities" defaultColumns="true" dojoType="dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore" count="100" var="rowActivity">
    <xe:this.columns>
    <xe:restViewColumn columnName="Activity"
         name="Activity">
                        </xe:restViewColumn>
                    </xe:this.columns>
                </xe:viewItemFileService>
            </xe:this.service>
        </xe:restService>

<xe:djFilteringSelect id="djfsActivity" trim="true"
                        promptMessage="Please type the first letter of intended activity"
                        invalidMessage="No activity found.  Please type again"
                        store="activityStore" searchAttr="Activity" labelAttr="Activity"
                        pageSize="10">
                    </xe:djFilteringSelect>
```

Comment: I found this error:Error: Unable to resolve constructor for: 'dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore'.  What cause this?

Comment: It is now working by adding this  <script type="text/javascript">
  dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");
 </script>
to my xpages.

Comment: The better way is add resource dojo module in xpages